# Unable to commit in Git

Tags: git, git-add

When I enter in console:

```
$   git add .
```

I get:

> Nothing added Nothing Specified. May be you wanted to say 'git add.'?

Comment: Is your cwd empty when you do this?

Answer (score 4):

Try this: `$ git commit -am "Your commit message"`

Comment: As far as I know `git add` is something else than `git commit`. Maybe you can tell what the difference is before wildly suggesting something.

Comment: Here you can do `add` and `commit` through one command! Is not it?

Comment: The `-a` option of `commit` adds only the files that were already tracked to the index, before creating the commit. OP apparently wants to add new files.

Comment: Yes! It won't add untracked files.

Answer (score 2):

### There is nothing to commit

if `git add .` doesn't do anything there are two possibilities:

- the directory you are in is empty
- Everything in the folder is already tracked and hasn't changed **OR** is ignored

e.g. with an empty folder:

```
$ git add .
$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
$ ls -la
drwxrwxr-x  3 andy andy 4096 Aug 26 11:34 .
drwxrwxrwt 11 andy andy 4096 Aug 26 11:34 ..
drwxrwxr-x  7 andy andy 4096 Aug 26 11:34 .git
```

Or, if everything is already tracked and unchanged:

```
$ touch foo
$ git add foo
$ git commit -m "adding foo"
[master (root-commit) d27092b] adding foo
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 foo
$ git add .
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
$ ls -la
drwxrwxr-x  3 andy andy 4096 Aug 26 11:34 .
drwxrwxrwt 11 andy andy 4096 Aug 26 11:34 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 andy andy    0 Aug 26 11:35 foo
drwxrwxr-x  7 andy andy 4096 Aug 26 11:34 .git
```

Note that git status did not report any changes.

### Ignored?

If a file/folder is ignored git will, well, ignore it :)

However you can still add it explicitly:

```
$ echo "bar" > .gitignore
$ touch bar
$ git add bar
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
bar
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added
$ git add -f bar
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   bar
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .gitignore
$
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `git add -A`. This should add all to staging area (new files etc.)

From manual:

> Like -u, but match  against files in the working tree in addition to the index. That means that it will find new files as well as staging modified content and removing files that are no longer in the working tree.

Answer (score 0):

The order should look like this:

**1)** start a branch: `git checkout -b my_cool_branch`
**2)** do stuff on that branch
**3)** add the things you've changed to your commit queue: `git add .`
**4)** commit the things you added to your queue: `git commit -m "i'm adding stuff!"`

(optionally)
**5)** switch back to master (or whatever your main branch is): `git checkout master`
**6)** push your local commits to your github: `git push origin master`

The error you're seeing makes me think that you've skipped step 2 - are you sure you've made changes?  run `git status` to see tracked/untracked changes.

Comment: @ dax i am pretty new to git.i have complete 2 task.now i want to commit both these task......these are the instructions given to me to commit.........please check this :  Say the ticket number you are working ins AS-3 then your git commits should be as below

git add .

git commit -am "AS3 - Description of change"

git push origin master

Comment: type `git status` - what does that give you?

Answer (score -1):

Use the git `commit`

```
$ git commit -m "Yeah am saving it!."
```

Comment: @ Shankar is there need to  add          $ git add???or i can add directly $ git commit -m "Yeah am saving it!." Thanks

Comment: @Neha, you can even do the add and save at the same time. `git add-commit -m 'Yeah thats a commit'`